# SVM with Matlab

Tags: matlab, svm

I am trying to perform SVM on the data set of the following kind.

There are many predicates say (Predicates: P1,P2,p3..Pn) and each predicate is associated with a class variable V.And each predicate  can be of three types and each type will have a value associated with it, e.g.

```
(P1,red)=5  (Class 0)
(p1,green)=10 (class 1)
(p1,yellow)=15 (class 1)

(p2,red)=9(class 1)
(p2,green)=99(class 1)
(p2,yellow)=1( Class 0).
```

In this case how should i split the variables and use SVM in MATLAB? Also there would be some predicates which may have certain values missing. For example, (p4,red) might be missing.

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: @EitanT My question was how do is give the Input to Matlab?In the below SVMStruct = svmtrain(Training,Group) how should i form Training Matrix? Should I take (p1,red),(p1,green),(p1,yellow) as different variables?

Comment: Did you read the [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/svmtrain.html)? It says [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/svmtrain.html#inputarg_Training) that each row in the training matrix corresponds to an observation, and each column corresponds to a feature. So if you have 3 features and 10 observations, your training matrix should be 10-by-3.